# VueJs textarea does not show the stored information when editing

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I am using Vuejs and have, inside a form, a textarea field.

When editing i can not see the value, inside the textarea.

If i save i do not lose the previous information as expected.

If i edit it stores the data as expected.

I only can not find, how to present the textarea value, when editing.

Inside a v-for loop i have the textarea that extendes a parent textarea template :

```html
<row v-for="(field, index) in fields" :key="index">
<div v-if="field.formType === 'textarea'">    
<va-textarea 
        :id="field.index" 
        v-model='formInput[index]' 
        v-bind:value="formValue[index]"
    ></va-textarea>
```

The field is defined in the data property :

```
data () {
    return {
        fields: {
            Commentts: {
                label     : 'Commentts',
                sortable  : false,
                type      : 'textarea',
                formType  : 'textarea',
                formReadOnly : false
            }
```

And i have the formSave method to insert or edit:

```
methods: {      
    formSave() {
        if ( this.formValue.Id === undefined) {
            this.formInput.Motivo_Id = this.formInput.Motivo.id
        }
        this.saveButton = true;
        this.formLoading= true;
        this.axios.post('Courses/save',
            {
                "data": { Id       : this.formValue.Id,
                          Date     : this.saveDateTime(this.formInput.Date),
                          faculty_Id: this.formInput.faculty_Id,
                          Commentts: this.formInput.Commentts
                        },
                 "route"        : this.$route.name,
            }).then((response) => {
```

How can i show the textarea information when editing the form ?

Comment: Please provide the complete structure of your data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks strange but let's figure out.

1. Loop

```html
<row v-for="(field, index) in fields" :key="index">
```

By your example `fields` is the object and variable `index` contains value "Commentts" and not an index. Is it what you want?

2. Data propagation

```html
<va-textarea 
    :id="field.index" 
    v-model='formInput[index]' 
    v-bind:value="formValue[index]"
></va-textarea>
```

I know nothing about `va-textarea` component implementation but I hope parameters `v-model` and `:value` were configured properly.

And with current implementation component's `data` field must contain `and`:

```
data () {
    return {
        fields: {
            Commentts: {
                .....
            },
        formInput: {
            Commentts: ...some data...
        },
        formValue: {
            Commentts: ...some data...
        },

Because declaration `v-model='formInput[index]'` requires `formInput` field in the root of the data field with `Commentts` inside.
```

Comment: there is this conditional div around the textareas field: <div v-if="field.formType === 'textarea'">

Comment: @ÂngeloRigo yes, I see your update. but you haven't provided the declaration of `formValue` field.

Comment: It is a project based on https://github.com/devjin0617/vue2-admin-lte the text area inherits from a template

Comment: https://github.com/devjin0617/vue2-admin-lte/blob/master/src/components/VATextarea.vue

Comment: <textarea
    :type="type"
    :id="vaId"
    :placeholder="placeholder"
    @input="$emit('input', $event.target.value)"
    :disabled="isDisabled"
    v-bind:value="model"
    v-bind:mask="mask" 
    :rows="rowCount"
    :class="[formControl, getSize]"
  ></textarea>